# Check whether a Unicode code point is assigned

Tags: go, unicode, codepoint

Go has the `unicode` package, containing useful functions such as `IsGraphic` or `IsPrint`. One function that is missing though is `IsAssigned`. Of course I could write my own function by using the other functions. But I would rather expect the standard library to provide this function. In Java, writing this function is easy:

```
boolean isAssigned(int codePoint) {
    return Character.getType(codePoint) != Character.UNASSIGNED;
}
```

In Go there is no function `unicode.Type(rune)` or `unicode.IsAssigned(rune)`. The closest I could find is this:

```
func IsAssigned(r rune) bool {
    return unicode.IsControl(r) ||
            unicode.IsGraphic(r) ||
            unicode.IsSymbol(r)
}
```

But that code thinks that U+00AD (soft-hyphen) is unassigned, which is wrong.

How can I get correct information about unassigned code points?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can verify a code point is *assigned* or *not* using [`unicode.Is`](https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/#Is) and `unicode.Categories` (though it is not efficient), i.e.

```
func IsAssigned(r rune) bool {
    for _, v := range unicode.Categories {
        if unicode.Is(v, r) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Working example is in [The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/UvQeho7S7sj).

Comment: are you sure that all assigned characters belong to some category? (it is kind of obvious, but maybe you have a quick proof)

Comment: actually code below shows 260+K runes belong to categories, while there is only ~130K codepoints assigned. Do I do something wrong? https://play.golang.org/p/gIcNVHa5PG6